# How to add class for many similar elements parent with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, size, parent, addclass

i have this markup:

```
<div class="fr_fieldsets_block">
   <fieldset>data</fieldset>
   <fieldset>data</fieldset>
   <fieldset>data</fieldset>
   <fieldset>data</fieldset>
</div>

<div class="fr_fieldsets_block">
   <fieldset>data</fieldset>
   <fieldset>data</fieldset>
</div>
```

Now: i need to add some class for `fr_fieldsets_block` element if it have more than 3 `fieldset` elements. I'v try with size method but function add my wish class for every `fr_fieldsets_block` block. How can i execute this for real? This is my js:

```
var fr_fieldsets_block = $('.fr_fieldsets_block'),
    filter_row_fieldset = fr_fieldsets_block.find('fieldset');
filter_row_fieldset.filter(function(){return $(this).size() >= 3;})
    .parent().addClass('scroll-pane');
```

thx, for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.fr_fieldsets_block').filter(function() {
   return $('fieldset', this).length > 2; // >= 3
}).addClass('scroll-pane');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5esLP/

Comment: works perfect, much thx for help, i known that will be some problems with that filter method :) thx again

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski You are welcome, actually you should filter parent elements not it's children.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.fr_fieldsets_block').find('fieldset').length >= 3)
 {
     $(this).addClass('scroll-pane');
 }
```

Comment: I tried to do it this way, but i guess there is some problem with lenght method, not working but thx for help ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(".fr_fieldsets_block").each(function(){
     var fieldSetLength=$(this).find('fieldset').length;
     if(fieldSetLength>3){
       $(this).addClass('newClass');
     }
   });
```